# Font-family not working properly on live server

Tags: css, browser, font-face

I am using **font-family "angelina"**. Its working properly on local server. But its not working on live server. It also working on live server just only on my computer. But its not working on any other computers.
I check it in all browsers on other computers but its not working.
I am using CSS code like this

```
@font-face {
font-family: MyCustomFont;
src: url("ANGELINA.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
 font-family: MyCustomFont;
 src: url("ANGELINA.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
.test_font{
    font-family: angelina;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the paths?

Comment: I check the path, its correct

Answer (score 3):

You need to have all kinds of font extensions on server to support all browsers.

@font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;

```
src: url('ANGELINA.eot');
src: url('ANGELINA.eot?') format('&#9786;'),
     url('ANGELINA.woff') format('woff'),
     url('ANGELINA.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('ANGELINA.svg#webfontssbCkuz5') format('svg');
```

}

You can find all font extensions on this site http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to be:

```
@font-face {
font-family: angelina;
src: url("ANGELINA.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
}
@font-face {
 font-family: angelina;
 src: url("ANGELINA.TTF") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
}
```

if you want to call `font-family: angelina;`