# Century Gothic font not showing on web page

Tags: html, css

on this web page http://nkarch.lifeintheuktest.co/the-work.aspx
The century gothic font is not showing e.g. in the top navigation ( THE WORK, NK, THE PRACTICE ). Any ideas? It should appear as its appearing in http://www.identifont.com/show?1N2

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233601/font-family-not-working-properly-on-live-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233601/font-family-not-working-properly-on-live-server)

Comment: Is this issue browser-specific, or happening in all browsers?

Comment: Its happening in all browsers. Though its showing on certain pages. e.g. http://nkarch.lifeintheuktest.co/the-practice.aspx its coming fine in address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare in your CSS that an `a` element should be Open Sans. Since that's more specific than your `li` font specification, it takes precedence.

To fix it, specify the font on `li a`

Answer (score 1):

You use `Open sans`.
Your `a` styles are inherited from the parent `.TopNavigation li {` styles.
so set `Century Gothic` font-family directly to your `li > a` elements.
If needed add the `!important`.

Comment: But try to avoid the `!important` thing...it's a hint that your CSS might not be as well formed as it could be.